# Protocol referencing another protocol via a property crash SourceKitService and Playground

Tags: swift

I'm experimenting with protocols and delegates and figured this should be possible:

```
protocol MyProtocolDelegate {
    func myProtocolDidThat(myProtocol: MyProtocol)
}

protocol MyProtocol {
    var delegate: MyProtocolDelegate? { get set }
}
```

However, the SourceKitService will crash again and again if I use the above code in Playground or a project. If I compile it gives:

```
Swift Compiler Error - Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

If I change `MyProtocol` to  a class everything works fine. Is this is Swift bug or a deliberate restriction? Looking at Swift with a Java background, where interfaces referencing interfaces isn't unusual, I'm a bit puzzled that this happens with Swift.

I'm using Xcode 6.0.1.

Comment: That looks like a bug. Happened a few times, last one yesterday when trying to pass a closure to another closure - in the end I implemented that in a different way.

Comment: I filed a bug, guess it won't hurt...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in question works as expected in Xcode 6.1, so it can be written of as a bug in Xcode 6.0.